# How to display variable name and not its value

Tags: bash

Here is what I have.

```
Server1=$(echo 192.168.0.1)
Server2=$(echo 192.168.0.2)
Server3=$(echo 192.168.0.3)

servers=($Server1 $Server2   $Server3)

for online in ${servers[@]}
do
ping $online -c2 > /dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
echo successful
else
echo “Cannot connect to “${!online}
fi
done
```

Right now it outputs “Cannot connect to “
I would like it to say “Cannot connect to Server1 or any others.

Comment: You should use an associative array then, so you can store the name as the key and use it for your error message.

Comment: `$(echo 192.168.0.1)` is like `$(echo $(echo $(echo 192.168.0.1))))`. Just `Server1=192.168.0.1`

Comment: That's what https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System is for, so you can `ping server1`

Comment: The trick of different solutions is storing the name of the server in the array, not the ip-address. With the name in a variabele you can also get the ip-address.

Answer (score 2):

You may just store the names in the array and use indirect expansion to get the values:

```
Server1=192.168.0.1
Server2=192.168.0.2
Server3=192.168.0.3
servers=(Server1 Server2 Server3)

for online in "${servers[@]}"; do
    if ping "${!online}" -c2 > /dev/null; then
         echo successful
    else
         echo "Cannot connect to ${online} with ip ${!online}"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes and things that can be improved in your script.

```
echo “Cannot connect to “${!online}
```

The environment variable `online` contains an IP address. Incidentally, the same IP address is also stored in one of the variables `Server1`, `Server2` or `Server3` but there isn't any link between them.

Using the indirection expansion (`${!online}`) will not bring you the name of the variable. The indirection expansion works the other way around. If `online` contains the name of another environment variable then `${!online}` is the value of that variable.

Let `servers` contain not the values but the names of the variables `Server1`, `Server2` and `Server3`, use the indirection expansion (`${!online}`) to get the IP address to ping and use `$online` to get the name of the variable that stores it.

---

```sh
Server1=$(echo 192.168.0.1)
```

This statement basically says: display `192.168.0.1` but do not put it on screen; capture the value and store it in the variable `Server1`.
It is not incorrect but it is just a convoluted (and wasteful) way to put a value in a variable. Put it directly like this:

```sh
Server1=192.168.0.1
```

---

```sh
ping $online -c2 > /dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
```

While this is not incorrect either, it can be written in a simpler (and sometimes faster) form by putting the command directly in the `if` statement:

```sh
if ping $online -c2 > /dev/null; then
```

---

Using the fixes and suggestions above, the complete script looks like this:

```sh
Server1=192.168.0.1
Server2=192.168.0.2
Server3=192.168.0.3

servers=(Server1 Server2 Server3)

for online in ${servers[@]}; do
  if ping ${!online} -c2 > /dev/null; then
    echo Successful
  else
    echo Cannot connect to $online.
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code for printing the name of the variable seems mostly correct, but to print the name of the variable you need `${!online@}`. However, this will just print "online", not Server1, etc. The comments point out the best way is an associative array, like this:

```sh
declare -A Servers=([Server1]=$(echo 192.168.0.1) 
                    [Server2]=$(echo 192.168.0.2) 
                    [Server3]=$(echo 192.168.0.3))

for key in "${!Servers[@]}"; do
    ping "${Servers["$key"]}" -c2 > /dev/null

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo successful
    else
        echo "Cannot connect to $key"
    fi
done
```

You could also do this with indirect variable references, like so:

```sh
Server1=$(echo 192.168.0.1)
Server2=$(echo 192.168.0.2)
Server3=$(echo 192.168.0.3)

servers=(Server1 Server2 Server3)

for name in ${servers[@]}; do
    ping "${!name}" -c2 > /dev/null

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo successful
    else
        echo "Cannot connect to $name"
    fi
done
```

Comment: As others have pointed out, you can also just use, for example, `Server1=192.168.0.1' instead of the command expansion, but I left the command expansion in place in case the addresses are being generated rather than directly input.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

- keep the current `Server*` assignments but eliminating the sub-process (`$(echo ...)`)
- keep the current array assignment
- keeping in mind that array indices start with `0`

We can make a few changes to the OP's current code:

```
Server1="98.137.11.164"                                                # a yahoo.com address
Server2="172.217.1.14"                                                 # a google.com address
Server3="192.168.0.3"                                                  # a bogus address (from my linux host)

servers=( "${Server1}" "${Server2}" "${Server3}" )

for i in "${!servers[@]}"                                              # obtain the array indices (0-2)
do
    if ping "${servers[${i}]}" -c2 > /dev/null                         # ping the ip address associated with array index $i
    then
         echo "successful [ Server$((i+1)) = ${servers[${i}]} ]"       # increment array index +1 to get server number
    else
         echo "Cannot connect [ Server$((i+1)) = ${servers[${i}]} ]"
    fi
done
```

Running the above from my linux host generates:

```
successful [ Server1 = 98.137.11.164 ]
successful [ Server2 = 172.217.1.14 ]
Cannot connect [ Server3 = 192.168.0.3 ]
```

**NOTE**: If server 'names' were to be something a bit more descriptive (eg, 'yahoo#1', 'google#13', etc) then I'd want to look at a solution based on an associative array where the array indices are the server names.

Answer (score 0):

When you want two (or more) variables in your loop, ou can use a here-document:

```
while IFS= read -r host ip; do
    if ping "${ip}" -c2 > /dev/null; then
         echo "${host} successful"
    else
         echo "Cannot connect to ${host} with ip ${ip}"
    fi
done  << @
   Server1 192.168.0.1
   Server2 192.168.0.2
   Server3 192.168.0.3
@
```

or when you want to use an array:

```
servers=(Server1=192.168.0.1 Server2=192.168.0.2 Server3=192.168.0.3)

for pair in ${servers[@]}; do
   IFS="=" read -r host ip <<< "${pair}"
   if ping "${ip}" -c2 > /dev/null; then
      echo "${host} successful"
   else
      echo "Cannot connect to ${host} with ip ${ip}"
   fi
done
```